# Cannot install php-imagick on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: php, imagick, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install the php module for imagemagick on my ubuntu server:

```
#@server:/#$ sudo apt-get install php-imagick
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 php-imagick : Hängt ab von: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: phpapi-20151012
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

The server runs Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0.8

```
#@server:/#$ php -v
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

So everything should be up to date ...

Is there currently no compatible imagick module for php7 available or does my php installation cause the problem?

What are the next steps to get this working?

Comment: Try this information: https://github.com/EasyEngine/easyengine/issues/695

Comment: I installed various php module before imagick - also updated and upgraded apt

Comment: Still not working - googled this problem, but couldn't find something useful.

Comment: I tried to install php-dev to add php-imagick via pecl, also not working: `php-dev : Hängt ab von: php7.0-dev soll aber nicht installiert werden`

Comment: I think this package causes the error: `libpcre3-dev : Hängt ab von: libpcre3 (= 2:8.38-3.1) aber 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 soll installiert werden`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happened. For me removing php-common and then installing php-imagick worked.

Note: apt-get remove php-common will also remove other libraries like php-cli php-mysql etc. but you can install that latter again, in case you want it.